# I'm getting 404 ERROR in admin page login magneto in localhost

Tags: localhost, magento2

I tried to setup Magento in my localhost. I setup installation then it showing this error when opening the admin page

I tried `.htacess` file. updating cache. none of this working

*this is an error on page 404* 
 [this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLTbz.png)

Comment: Hi @mohit. Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please restructure the error page details or attach the screenshot of the error page. the information is really not readable.

Comment: Hi there, I make changes to the error page plz check if you have the solution for this error.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue and managed to fix it.
A number of causes that turned out to be the culprit behind this error.
So, firstly check the Magento logs such as exception.log and system.log and PHP error logs to find out where the problem originates.

Which magento version you are using ? If you can provide me the error details, then probably I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the **error reporting** and set the display errors in **bootstrap.php**. then check the log files.